# Dart api exception Errors( Error Handling), how to handle exception json

Tags: flutter, dart

Im calling api and i got exception i want to handle that values how to access those values using dart

```
ApiException 401: {"errorCode":"DATA__001","values":{"param1":"Final"},"violations":null}
```

Ihave tried this way but no luck

```
var error=jsonDecode('ApiException 401: {"errorCode":"DATA__001","values":{"param1":"Final"},"violations":null}');
```

Answer (score 0):

the http.get return a Future and that Future has an Object of Type http.Response.
and that Object has the property that name is statusCode .it store your response Code from the Server.
that is an example of how you can catch the code and work with a response as you like.

```
 Future<http.Response> response = http.get('your api url');  
    response.then((http.Response responseData) {
          if (responseData.statusCode==200) {
            //do somthing
          }else{
            // do somthing else
          }
    }
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it was flagged for review. Answers with no explanation are often considered low-quality. Please provide some commentary in the answer for why this is the correct answer.

Comment: do you know why if the answer correct no body add +1 ?

Comment: Assuming it's right, it just happens.  Often the questioner is the only one to +1 and even they often don't.